Implement a discussion ban system similar to the question ban
While people that are question banned can't post on discussions, nothing is happening to those who abuse discussions and post all their low quality questions there. Because these people never post questions, they are never hit with a question ban, and therefore, never blocked from posting on discussions. There is no consequence for these users who hurt the site with their really bad discussions.
I've witnessed the same user keep posting their really bad questions on discussions. While most of their discussions should be on the main Q&A site, they post them on discussions instead. While I'm not too sure why they do this, it could be because they are trying to avoid a question ban.
While discussions can't be downvoted, discussion flags can be used as a good metric for low quality content. If a user's discussions are repeatedly being flagged or getting removed, the system should block that user from posting on discussions. User's can regain their discussions permissions by posting better content on other sections of the site, such as by posting good questions and answers.

"people never post questions" That, or post a question, get downvoted, then start posting on Discussions.

I mean, or, just get rid of discussions

being able to flag a discussion is already a big achievement. Some months ago that was not possible... related: Should I flag a discussion that is actually a bad question?

@Ðаո some previous feature requests have been implemented. One example is users that are question banned can't post discussions

This is one that is likely to get implemented, given that it would reduce the arguments against discussions existing by reducing the amount of garbage getting posted.

Are discussions coming up in search engine results in any significant amount yet?

They do, if you search for something such that you'd expect it to.

I doubt very much this would get implemented. If flags are the only quality metric you can't really "edit discussions to improve discussion quality" since the bad would already be removed, and you'd need to weigh flags by (random) upvotes to determine net-positive to net-negative. I don't think that they can make a reliable discussion ban system without re-implementing downvotes. If anything, they could ban the worst of the worst, with no real recourse available for banned users.

Yeah I still don't know what discussions are intended for exactly - why did "the company" add that Reddit feature? The fact that it has actually been fixed that people who can't post questions also can't post discussions does not imply that is a permanent fix. It might just be to ease in this new feature which is going to be the main money maker of the site. At this point I don't think we are qualified to say what does and does not "hurt" the site, only what hurts you personally.
